# Where to find API_KEY for google maps (Android App)?

Tags: android, google-maps

Where to find the API_KEY for using the Google Maps API? (as referenced at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_a_map)

I am at the Google Cloud Console but cannot see the "API_KEY" here.

[image]

Comment: Follow that link http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-application-setup/

Answer (score 0):

You have to goto APIs & Auth >Registered Apps>your App Name (If you have already registered your app) else you need to register your app in the same page it self